# How to get a list of users who allowed my application?

Tags: facebook

I want to get users who allowed my application to get their facebook information.

Example: I have 60 persons allowed my application, Can I get information of list 60 person who allowed my application?

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without saving the user ids to a database there is no call to retrieve the list of users that installed your application.